# Additional ways of running programs at logon

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7

Googling has yielded three methods of running a script at login so far:

- Putting it into startup folder
- Add a task to the task scheduler
- Add it to the logon script in the group policy manager

Unfortunately, the software that I am using to configure VMs runs windows setup again in order to apply its settings to the VM after creating a clone of the template. This process seems to remove the changes to those areas. So, are there any other methods to set a script to run at logon?

Comment: This looks it will help you out. http://superuser.com/questions/15596/automatically-run-a-script-when-i-log-on-to-windows

Comment: Thanks, cloning a VM with that set now. Hopefully it will propagate correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method through the Windows Registry.

The keys:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` - Runs programs for all users.

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` - Runs programs for current user.

To make a script run using these registry keys, you just need to create a `REG_SZ` value inside them, its values must contain the path to the script. The value name doesn't matters.

You can check the values using Windows Registry Editor (Regedit.exe) or using `reg query` command:

```
reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

You can also make these values using `reg add` command:

```
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v ValueName /t REG_SZ /d Path_to_script
```

You will need administrative privileges to add values.

Comment: Will this be preserved through setup, or will it overwrite the new registry keys?

Comment: It depends on the method already set. If there's no registry keys, so it will not overwrite.

Comment: The registry keys remain there after the cloning, but it doesn't actually start anything when I log in. The regedit stuff works on my template though, which is strange.

Comment: Because I kept the scripts in the documents of the administrator user, they were deleted when setup replaced the old system administrator with its new system administrator, therefore, the paths were invalid. I'm surprised that with all the methods I tried, I didn't once get such an error message. Everything works now.